# Graphite Sync Db throws error The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: graphite, rhel7

I have installed Graphite in RHEL7 server using the source. I have created a database in Postgresql. Modified the local_settings.py with Postgresql database.

When I execute the below command for sync, it throws an error

```
PYTHONPATH=/app/graphite/webapp django-admin.py migrate --settings=graphite.settings --run-syncdb
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('Django==2.2.1', 'django-admin.py')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1446, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/core/checks/database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 216, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "/app/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.2.1-py3.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 176, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

The `SECRET_KEY` is added in local_settings.py, app_settings.py and settings.py. But still it thorws the same error. I have done the fresh installation of graphite and modified the DB values.